# SOCK_STREAM socket listen() causing TCP syn/ack to be sent

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, freebsd

I have a socket set up  to accept TCP connections with

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
```

and I am then calling `bind()`, `listen()` and `accept()`

The problem is that when I call listen(), it is causing a SYN/ACK packet to be sent to the client. I thought that would not happen until I called accept(), but what's worse is that the SYN/ACK packet doesnt have the acknowledgement increased by one.

What is causing this, and how can I fix it?

Thanks

As a side note - does it matter that my TCP connection is asymmetric?

Comment: If this is a mainstream TCP implementation, it is unlikely that it is misbehaving.  Is the client trying to connect before the server calls listen() ?   If so, and if it hasn't timed out, perhaps that somewhat unusual (but by no means illegal) order of events means the proper behavior is a bit different from what you expect.

Comment: Well, that is actually true. I am actually intercepting some traffic, and standing up the socket to listen() AFTER the client has tried to connect (client being wget). This is kind of like a just-in-time port forwarding that I am trying to implement

Comment: In the wireshark capture I am also seeing that the client tries multiple times in the TCP session to send the SYN packet. I would think that even if it failed on the first one, I'd be able to accept it the second time

Comment: Post a minimal example which causes the problem.

Comment: You're probably not going to get any useful answers without code.

Comment: That may take some time. There is no minimal example without all of the firewall rules and stuff that makes this code work.

Comment: I am using a differnet thread for each "dynamic" socket I am standing up. Am I able to have multiple threads each use the same socket/port and be assured their data wont get mixed up when they read/write to the socket? If so, I could do that instead and have the socket created ahead of time I suppose, if it is possible.

Comment: @Derek You seem pretty confused. Normally you will have a thread per accepted socket, i.e. per client, so there is nothing to get mixed up.

Comment: I have one client, many connections. I need a socket per connection, per port. This is because I am accepting connections on a full port range. It's not like a web server where I would have multiple connections on the same port.

Comment: So you still need a thread per socket, maybe two, one to read, one to write. Or possibly use poll(). You certainly don't want multiple threads writing to the same socket: the interleaving could happen any way at all. All you know is that what each send() is atomic, i.e. all that data goes together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the normal operation of the TCP 'backlog' queue. It is a queue of connections that the stack has already completed but the application hasn't accepted yet. The size of this queue is set by the second argument to listen(), although the platform can adjust it up or down (usually up).

Whatever you observed about the sequence number is bound to be correct behaviour as well, otherwise nothing would work.

Comment: If the backlog queue is set to zero, will this force the kernel to wait to accept something until I am ready to call accept() implicitly?

Comment: @Derek No. The kernel will silently enforce its minimum, which could be 5 or 500. Why would you want zero?

Answer (score 3):

The implementation of TCP on your machine may choose to actually "accept" the incoming connection the moment you call `listen`. This actually makes sense, to avoid unnecessary delays due to "lazy" accepts. Just to remind you, one of the parameters of `listen` is the so-called backlog number, i.e. the amount of "buffered" accepts pending.

Regarding the incrementing of ACK in syn+ack datagram. I don't remember what the protocol states, but this is probably the correct behavior during handshake.

Comment: I agree that is correct behavior to increment it. I just always assumed it happened during the "accept" phase of the connection.

Comment: @Derek It *does* happen during the "accept" phase of the connection, but that phase usually happens before the application calls the accept() function.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answers and comments, this is the actual standard behavior the TCP implementation.

In case you insist on explicitly completing the TCP handshake by accepting incoming connection in the application you have platform a dependent solution.

For Windows stack you can set `SO_CONDITIONAL_ACCEPT` socket option on the listening socket. See [winsock documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-setsockopt).